# Manipulating Existing Excel Workbook Using Python

Tags: python, excel

I have code that will allow me to open an excel workbook and also write into existing excel sheets.

Currently I am using `wb = copy(temp)` which copies an existing template that has tables, graphs, formulas within some cells, and Names. After I copy the workbook and save under a new name, I lose all of the previously noted objects.

My question is: Is it possible to copy an excel workbook with all of the pre-existing tables, graphs, etc. and save the file after adding data to selected cells?

- [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK2NS.jpg) of Python code producing excel sheet without correct formatting
- [Excel sample sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpQFn.jpg), this is what the output should look like

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io) package. Here's a simple example:

```
import openpyxl

# Grab first worksheet of existing excel file
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

# Write some cell values
ws['A1'] = 18
ws['A2'] = 39

# Save changes to excel file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution!